# Float drop with div tags in footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float a div to the right of my footer after 2 other divs (ie 3 columns) and want them to line up horizontally but the one I'm floating right keeps dropping down below the 2 on the left. Can anyone help with this?

Here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>K Blondel Design :: Carpentry &amp; Funiture Design :: Brighton</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link href="oneColFixCtr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Cutive+Mono|Nothing+You+Could+Do' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="subcontainer">


<div class="header">

<div id="mainNav">

  <ul id="mainNav">
  <li><a href="#" id="homelink" target="_self">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="aboutuslink" target="_self">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="ourworklink" target="_self">Our Work </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contactuslink" target="_self">Contact Us </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div class="contact">
E : click here
  <br />
  T : 07585 607521 
</div>
</div>


<div class="lineborder">
</div>

      <div class="sidebar-logo"><img src="Images/k-blondel-design-logo.png" width="64" height="108" alt="K Blondel Design logo" />
    </div>

      <div id="contentright">

      <div class="galleryimg"><div class="photo"><img src="Images/winebar-furniture-01.jpg" width="145" height="200" alt="Winchester winebar" /></div></div>

      <div class="galleryimg"><div class="photo"><img src="Images/wooden-outdoor-seating.jpg" width="145" height="200" alt="Winchester winebar" /></div></div>

      <div class="galleryimg"><div class="photo"><img src="Images/wooden-shelving.jpg" width="145" height="200" alt="Winchester winebar" /></div></div>

      <div class="galleryimg"><div class="photo"><img src="Images/wooden-winerack.jpg" width="145" height="200" alt="Winchester winebar" /></div></div>


      </div> 


  <div id="content">
    <h1>Instructions    </h1>
    <p>At K Blondel Design we aim to fill the gap between the over exuberant furniture maker and the general carpenter. Trained in the art of creating affordable and elegant solutions to 3D problems.</p>
    <p>As a small business we are able to deliver a personal one to one design service, talking through various design and material possibilities and arriving at an affordable, bespoke and stylish solution.</p>
    <p>From design through to construction and installation we specialise in storage solutions, furniture and interiors for both the domestic and commercial markets. </p>
    <p>Based in Brighton we have 20 years' design and commercial experience and an ever-growing client list spanning Sussex, Hampshire, London and Kent.</p>

    <p>
      <!-- end .content --></p>
  </div>


     <div class="lineborder"></div>

    <div id="footer">


    <div class="footercolleft">
      <a href="#">Carpentry</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Furniture Design</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Interior Design &amp; Decoration</a>
</div>
    <div class="footercolright">
      <a href="#">Storage Solutions</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Decking &amp; Wooden Flooring</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Shop Fitting / Commercial Interiors</a>
</div>

   <div class="footercoladdress">
      Copyright © 2014 Kevin Blondel Design<br />1 Park Terrace, Brighton BN1 0GT
</div> 
</div>
  <!-- end .subcontainer --></div>



  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the css...

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    font: 100%/1.4;
    background-color:#FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}

/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight: normal;    
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Cutive Mono', Georgia, serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.4em;
    font-weight:600;

}

#home #homelink,
#aboutus #aboutuslink,
#ourwork #ourworklink,
#contactus #contactuslink {
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #494949;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom: solid 6px #494949;
}

#mainNav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#mainNav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 14px 0 14px;
}

#mainNav a {
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #494949;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#mainNav a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #494949;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}
/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color: #494949;
    text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
    color: #494949;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds all other elements ~~ */
.container {
    width: 1352px;
    background-image:url(Images/sktchbook-bgd.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

.header {
    width: 950px;
    height: 72px;
    margin-left:90px;
    margin-right: 90px;
}

.header img{
    border:none;
}

.lineborder {
    width: 950px;
    background-color:#494949;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left:110px;
    margin-right:110px;
}

.contact {
    float: right;
    padding: 27px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #494949;
    font-size:17px;
}

.sidebar-logo {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
}

.subcontainer {
    width: 1150px;
    min-height: 880px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

/* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

*/
#content {

    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 420px;
    margin-left:90px;
    margin-right:90px;
    min-height:475px;
}

#contentright {
    float: right;
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 420px;
    margin-right:90px;

}

.galleryimg {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 40px 30px 0;
}

.photo {
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #888;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #888;
}

.photo img {
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the .container is removed */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

#footer {
    padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
    width: 950px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left:90px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #494949;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#footer a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #494949;
}

.footercolleft {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footercolright {
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footercoladdress {
    float:right;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width:250px;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: if floatting element is behind a non floatting element, it first do a line break, thats why it drops down. put it first  and see how it behaves or switch it or its rule with colright.

Answer (score 0):

When floating two items to the right, the one that comes first will actually go to the far right. And since you aren't floating the 'middle' column, it has a margin on the right that pushes the address column down.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e2W74/)**

Switch the order of your html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footercolleft">
        <a href="#">Carpentry</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Furniture Design</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Interior Design &amp; Decoration</a>
    </div>
    <div class="footercoladdress">
        Copyright © 2014 Kevin Blondel Design<br />1 Park Terrace, Brighton BN1 0GT
    </div> 
    <div class="footercolright">
        <a href="#">Storage Solutions</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Decking &amp; Wooden Flooring</a><br/>
        <a href="#">Shop Fitting / Commercial Interiors</a>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Worked fine once I added another 'overflow: hidden;' to the #footer css. Only thing is now I have a large gap between the bottom line and footer content. Not sure how that's happened?

Comment: #footer {
 padding: 0 0 0 20px;
 width: 950px;
 height: 150px;
 margin-left:90px;
 margin-right: 90px;
 font-family: 'Abel', Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #494949;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#footer a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

#footer a:hover {
 color:#FFF;
 background-color: #494949;
}

.footercolleft {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.footercolright {
 padding: 0;
 width: 200px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.footercoladdress {
 float:right;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
 text-align: right;
 width:250px;
}

Comment: Originally had 10px top padding on footer but it's as if a return is being put in some how. Made the top padding 0 but still a larger gap than I was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above comments. It was fixed as suggested above by re-ordering the html so that the right floating div came in between the 2 left hand columns. I also added another 'overflow: hidden' to the #footer properties.